# Matlab: Plot a subplot with hold on and hold off in a loop without always calling xlabel, ylabel, xlim, etc

Tags: matlab

Matlab question: this might be really simple but I can't figure it out...I'm pretty new. I have a plot window, broken up into two subplots, lets call them A and B, which have different labels and limits. I (hold on), make several plots to B, then I (hold off), then start iterating. In the loop, I want to update both A and B with NEW plots, but I want the axis labels, and xlim and ylim to stay the same, WITHOUT having to call xlabel, xlim, etc every iteration.

Now, (hold off) destroys all axis properties. How do I save the axis properties so I don't have to keep calling xlabel, etc in the loop? I've tried newplot, setting the Nextplot property, etc to no avail. I'd like a simple solution please...not something like re-writing the plot command. Thanks!

```
hfig=figure();
hax = axes('Parent',hfig);
plot(hax,x,y);
hold on
plot(hax,x1,y1);
%this hold off resets the axes
hold off
while (1)
  subplot('Position',[.07 .05 .92 .44]);
  %I want to do this without having to call xlabel, ylabel, etc
  %over and over
  plot(newx, newy);
  xlabel()
  ylabel()
  hold on
  plot(newx1, newx2)
  hold off
...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution here is to initialize your plot and axes properties before your loop, then within your loop set the [`'NextPlot'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#NextPlot) of the axes to `'replacechildren'` so that only the plot objects (and not the axes settings) will be changed on the next call to PLOT:

```
hFigure = figure();
hAxes = axes('Parent',hFigure);
plot(hAxes,x,y);
hold on;
plot(hAxes,x1,y1);
xlabel(...);  %# Set the x label
ylabel(...);  %# Set the y label
xlim([...]);  %# Set the x limits
ylim([...]);  %# Set the y limits
while (1)
  set(hAxes,'NextPlot','replacechildren');
  plot(hAxes,newx,newy);
  hold on;
  plot(hAxes,newx1,newx2);
  ...
end
```

This should maintain the settings for `hAxes` when new data is plotted in the loop.